# Rounding off .fillna values only. Not the entire column in python

Tags: python, rounding, fillna

I'm trying to create a function that will impute values based on a choice either mean or median.

I've managed to do so, my problem is that I want to round off only the values I impute. But the way I've done it is rounding off every value in the column, not only the filled values as required.

```
def conditional_impute(input_df, choice='median'):
    new_df = input_df.copy()
    
    if choice == 'median':
        new_df['Age'] = round(new_df.groupby(['Sex', 'Pclass'])['Age'].transform(func = lambda x: x.fillna(x.median())),1)
        
    elif choice == 'mean':
        new_df['Age'] = round(new_df.groupby(['Sex', 'Pclass'])['Age'].transform(func = lambda x: x.fillna(x.mean())),1)
        
    else:
        raise ValueError('Please choose either median or mean as your impute choice.')
    
    return new_df
```

So how can I round off only the imputed values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You apply the round function to the whole column. Did you try something like this and apply it to the median (or mean) only.

```
if choice == 'median':
        new_df['Age'] = new_df.groupby(['Sex', 'Pclass'])['Age'].transform(func = lambda x: x.fillna(round(x.median(),1)))
```

Comment: Thank you! I attempted that but had my round around the wrong set of brackets!